# How to implement nested do while loops in windows batch file?

Tags: batch-file

Here is my attempt but it keeps giving error -

```
set /a "x = 1"
echo %x%
:while1
    if %x% leq 3 (
        set /a "y = 1"

        :while2
          if %y% leq 4 (
               echo %y% 
               set /a "y = y + 1"               
               goto :while2
          )
        echo %x%  
        set /a "x = x + 1"
        goto :while1
    )
```

Error - 
    G:\A>set /a "x = 1"
    G:\A>echo 1
    1
    The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems.

1- The %y% doesn't work as expected, as it is expanded in the moment of parsing the parenthesis block, before it is executed.

```
if %x% leq 3 (
        set /a "y = 1"
          if %y% leq 4 (
...
```

Expands to

```
if 1 leq 3 (
        set /a "y = 1"
          if leq 4 (
...
```

You better use the delayed expansion !y!

2- Your syntax error is a result of a "First-Line-Label" just before a closing parenthesis.
Labels are allowed in parenthesis bocks, but they should always used in double lines.

3- goto-jumps always cancel all parenthesis blocks
This isn't a problem in your case, but in the most cases it isn't a good idea, to use goto's in a block

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a "x = 1"

echo %x%
:while1
if %x% leq 3 (
    set /a "y = 1"

    :while2
    :while2 This is the Second-Line-Label
    if !y! leq 4 (
        echo y=!y!
        set /a "y = y + 1"
        goto :while2
    )
    echo x=!x!
    set /a "x = x + 1"
    goto :while1
)
```